# simulators/Emulators available for IFE Android devices

Tags: android, appium

How to handle simulators/emulators for IFE Android devices? building TestAutomation for this device. So should understand simulators for the same.

Comment: By IFE you mean In Flight Entertainment? That question you may have to ask o to manufacturer of such systems.